# Blend image with background using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to "blend" an image with a background-color using CSS, so I tried:

```css
.bg-img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 90vh;
  opacity: 0.3;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 2%, #0f0f0f 80%);
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 2%, #0f0f0f 80%);
}
```

```html
<img class="bg-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/y7jfKaw.jpg">
```

And this basically worked, however the image doesn't look quite blended in with the background. It just looks like many "shade lines", like on the image below
[image]

And what I want is the bottom of the image to be blended better, something like the image below
[image]

Hope this makes sense and thx to anyone that helps in advance.

Comment: Please show the complete code that includes background-image.

Comment: There. Just edited the post.

Comment: It would help if you could link to an `<img>` that shows up in your document (using an image placeholder site, or Creative Commons image, if necessary).

Comment: I added the image to the snippet.